# Как в Python отсортировать список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, list

У меня есть список `a = [6, 3, 7, 3, 6 , 0, 8]` для примера. Как сделать так, чтобы было `a = [0, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8]`

То есть, потом я переберу этот список:

```py
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    print(a[i])
    a += 1
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Не пробовали открывать любое описание языка? и как вы себе представляете прибавление единицы к списку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массив сортируется при помощи `a.sort()` и запомните `print(a.sort())` будет `None`, то есть `.sort()` ничего не возращает

И ещё вы перебираете при помощи цикла `while`, хотя можно и при помощи `for`:

```py
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Comment: вы запускали этот код?

Comment: он выведет 7 раз список `a`

Answer (score 5):

Если надо не менять исходный список, а получить новый то лучше использовать `sorted`

```
a = [6, 3, 7, 3, 6 , 0, 8]
new_a = sorted(a)
```

также у вас неправильно сделан цикл `while`. Он должен быть таким:

```
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    print(a[i])
    i += 1
```

Но лучше использовать цикл `for`

```
for el in sorted(a):
    print(el)
```

Если вам нужен индекс элемента, то так:

```
a = sorted(a) 
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(i, a[i])
```

также можно использовать `enumerate`

```
for i, el in enumerate(sorted(a)):
    print(i, el)
```

Answer (score 3):

Пусть:

```
a = [6, 3, 7, 3, 6 , 0, 8]
```

Тогда его можно отсортировать 2 способами:

```
a = sorted(a)
```

Или:

```
a.sort()
```

Получиться:

```
print(' '.join(map(str,a)))
```

Вывод:

```
0 3 3 6 6 7 8
```

Comment: `print(' '.join(map(str,a)))` зачем так сложно, не легче будет просто `print(*a)`?

Comment: да, так тоже можно

Answer (score -2):

Что бы отсортировать список достаточно использовать

```
sort(a)
```

Comment: Сами уже попробовали так отсортировать?

Comment: на самом деле функция называется [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)